# Div radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have seen a few answers on here and the web but as I need to ask something else I have made this question. + I cant seem to get anything to work.

So what I'm after is `Yes` and `No` options, these will be buttons and when pressed they will stay active as they will make a `div` appear on the page depending on there value.

E.G:

Yes = `<div id="won">You won</div>`

No = `<div id="lose">You lost</div>`

These divs will appear under the buttons. My question is how can I get the value from a div? I tried to use radio buttons inside to get this working but I cant seem to do it.

What I have so far.

### HTML:

```
<div class="buttonHolder">
    <div class="option">Yes
        <input id="yes" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div class="option">No
        <input id="no" type="radio" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
div {
    outline: 1px solid;
}
.buttonHolder {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
}
.buttonHolder1 {
    background: red;
}
.option {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #eee;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.optiontest {
    background: #fff;
}
```

### jQuery:

```
$('.option').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var input = $this.find('input');
    $('.optiontest').toggleClass('optiontest');
    $(input).prop('checked', true);
    $(this).toggleClass('optiontest');

});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/bNNA6/)

So the buttons will look like that and change background when pressed as well as bringing up another question etc... There will be multiply questions and answers on the same page.

## Edit:

Forgot to add that I would like the radio button not visible, so it looks like the `div` is selected and there is no radio button. Apologises for not adding that when writing the question.

Comment: `data` attribute will help you out, i.e. `data-yes` and `data-no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can include the data attribute in the DIV

look at your jsfiddle, i have made some modification in HTMl and Jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/bNNA6/1/

```
 $('.option').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var input = $this.find('input');
        $('.optiontest').toggleClass('optiontest');
        $(input).prop('checked', true);
        $(this).toggleClass('optiontest');
        var dataValue = $this.data("optionvalue"); // using data attribute to put the value
        alert(dataValue);
    });
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I forgot to say in my question I don't really want the radio buttons visible. Sorry about that, updating my question now.

Comment: Using this one, thje radio buttons are not needed are they? when using this `data` attribute.

Comment: yes... you can completely remove the radio button if you want... updated your jsfiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/bNNA6/5/

Answer (score 0):

What about [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bNNA6/2/)?

The jQuery is pretty simple:

```
$('input[name="options"]').click(function () {
    $('.optiontest').removeClass('optiontest')
    $(this).closest('.option').toggleClass('optiontest')
});
```

And I modified your HTML to give the radio buttons values (you had it set as ID's) and the same name, which gives them the correct radio button behaviour.

```
<div class="buttonHolder">
    <div class="option">Yes
        <input name="options" value="yes" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div class="option">No
        <input name="options" value="no" type="radio" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited my question as I forgot a key point. But this is pretty much what I want but without the radio buttons visible.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help :-

http://jsfiddle.net/cNqV7/

```
<div class="buttonHolder">
<div class="option1">Yes

</div>
<div class="option2">No

</div>
```